# CodeIgniter com Blade?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel-blade

Estou começando a estudar `CI` e como usei um pouco de `Laravel` para facilitar estava tentando colocar o `Blade`, [segui este tutorial](http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/integrando-blade-template-engine-com-codeigniter/). Segui a risca o tutorial, mas retorna esses ***erros***:

> [image: log]

Como resolver esses problemas?

Comment: Não estava conseguindo colocar no post, mas coloquei no github: https://github.com/HenriqueBuzin/van

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é **mudança de versão**, o arquivo `blade.php` criado na pasta `application\libraries` deve conter o seguinte código, mediante configuração obtida no seu próprio [github: XiaoLer/blade](https://github.com/XiaoLer/blade), diferente do que está no tutorial, pois é antiga e a versão foi alterada, exemplo das alterações:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Blade
{
    private $factory;
    public function __construct()
    {        
        $path = [APPPATH . 'views/'];
        $cachePath = APPPATH . 'cache/views';        
        $file = new \Xiaoler\Blade\Filesystem;
        $compiler = new \Xiaoler\Blade\Compilers\BladeCompiler($file, $cachePath);       
        $compiler->directive('datetime', function($timestamp) {
            return preg_replace('/(\(\d+\))/', 
                    '<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $1); ?>', $timestamp);
        });
        $compiler->directive('now_datetime', function() {
            return '<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", '.(strtotime('now')).'); ?>';
        });        
        $resolver = new \Xiaoler\Blade\Engines\EngineResolver;
        $resolver->register('blade', function () use ($compiler) {
            return new \Xiaoler\Blade\Engines\CompilerEngine($compiler);
        });
        $this->factory = new \Xiaoler\Blade\Factory($resolver, 
                            new \Xiaoler\Blade\FileViewFinder($file, $path));
        $this->factory->addExtension('tpl', 'blade');
    }    
    public function view($path, $vars = [])
    {
        echo $this->factory->make($path, $vars);
    }
    public function exists($path)
    {
        return $this->factory->exists($path);
    }
    public function share($key, $value)
    {
        return $this->factory->share($key, $value);
    }
    public function render($path, $vars = [])
    {
        return $this->factory->make($path, $vars)->render();
    }
```

}

e nas `views` criadas deve seguir a nomenclatura `blade.php` exemplo:

- ***index.blade.php***
- ***home.blade.php***

para funcionar.

Para chamar o comando no seu `controller`:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function test()
    {
        $data['message'] = 'message 1';
        $this->blade->view('test_message', $data);
    }
}
```

a `view` seguindo a nomenclatura de nome ficando assim: `test_message.blade.php`

Outro ponto a observar é a criação da pasta de cache `application\cache\views`, como exemplo da figura logo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Observação:*** *só o arquivo* `blade.php` *deve ser modificado, o resto continua igual do tutorial*.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [github: XiaoLer/blade](https://github.com/XiaoLer/blade)
- [Laravel - Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

Comment: Olá, modifiquei os arquivos mencionados, mas ainda continua com alguns erros, coloquei a pasta com as imagens na raiz do git com o nome erros_images tentei fazer igual o explicado.

Comment: Esse código foi testado e funcionou, mas diga ai os erros por favor @henriquebuzin

Comment: @HenriqueBuzin se deu permissão de escrita e leitura na pasta ??? nas duas inclusive. está faltando isso eu acredito. tem como conferir se ele gera os arquivos nas duas pastas???

Comment: Eu usei chmod 777 recursivo em todo o projeto, mas ele continua com dois erros principais (acho que os outros derivam desses): Undefined index: config no core/Loader.php e file_put_contents(/Users/henrique_buzin/Sites/van/application/cache/views/5cf6b83b721d4d7c20fd127315dc5ae3fbb5aec9.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory no src/Filesystem.php coloquei um png de todos os erros no git na pasta erros_images: https://github.com/HenriqueBuzin/van/tree/master/erros_images sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: @HenriqueBuzin eu fiz uma edição, você criou a pasta de cache? igual está na edição.

Comment: Olá, fiz a edição agora, consertou quase tudo, so tem mais um erro, coloquei a foto no git tb, o erro é o seguinte: Undefined index: config e Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' parece que não esta reconhecendo a variavel, no fim mostra a mensagem assim: message. Sabe o que poderia ser? Abraço.

Comment: @HenriqueBuzin o seu `blade.php` esta diferente da resposta copie novamente. Qual é s linha 26!?